# Reference XML elements directly (in kotlin)

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-edittext

I am looking at an old project and noticed that I am unable to recreate the following:

```
var name = name.text.toString()
```

where name.text = an EditText element id in my activity_main.

I know this once worked.

I am asking because within my RealTime Firebase I want to query entries into different children based on a text value:
ex:  
    `ref.child("Main").child(edit-text-string data).setValue(some other edit-text-string data)`

I see now I need to find the element by id, 
I tried finding the edittext by id, assigning it to a variable and then passing the value.toString() to child() but the following code throws the following error

```
val text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
            val value = text.toString()
ref.child("main").child(value.toString()).setValue("testdata")

this throws an error     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{3b54811 VFED..CL. .F...... 0,0-1440,85 #7f0801d9 app:id/name aid=1073741824}. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

because it is interpreting value still as an object(?)

Can you think of a way to create childen 'headers' with text from the user?

Comment: If you're referring to Kotlin Synthetics, they've been deprecated and removed from the default setup. Current recommendations are to use [View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [Data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding). If you don't wanna use either of those, `findViewById()` is still available (and is what all of those are doing behind the scenes, anyway).

Comment: hmm figures, thanks Mike. Can you think of a way to achieve what I was getting at there?

Comment: `val value = text.toString()` – That's calling `toString()` directly on the `EditText`. You want to call it on the `EditText`'s text: `val value = text.text.toString()`. The fact that you chose `text` for the variable name there might've caused a little confusion.

Comment: ahhh okay, I see what you mean, Thank you

Comment: View binding is probably the easiest drop-in for what you already have - it's just all your view variables like ``name`` end up declared on a ``LayoutNameBinding`` object instead of on the activity/fragment. Typically you get a reference to that object (usually called ``binding``) and go ``binding.name.text.toString()``, or you can use Kotlin's scope functions like ``with(binding)`` or ``binding.apply`` to avoid repeating ``binding``, and that way you can wrap your code as-is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your old project seem to be using now deprecated [Kotlin Synthetics](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) which allowed you to access XML views simply by specifying their ids but its deprecated now and no longer added automatically by Android Studio to a new project, that is why you have to use `findViewById` instead, its recommended that you [migrate to ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Apart from this there are some issues in your code.

> where name.text = an EditText element id in my activity_main.

This is wrong, element id is `name`, `name.text` referes to the text property of `EditText`.

And when you get text from EditText

```
val text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
```

This gives you a reference to the `EditText`, if you want to get value of its `text` property as `String` then you will have to write `text.text.toString()`. `text.toString()` calls `toString` on the `EditText` object